# How to make the name of variables clear in the boxplot

Tags: r

I need to see names of variables written in the figure below because as you can see names of variables are written in a vertical way which prevents the reader sees them.

[image]

My code used to plot the boxplot is :

```
Data<-data.frame(hierarchical,df)
frameDataClusterGrpe1<-Data[which(Data$hierarchical==1),]
boxplot(frameDataClusterGrpe1,las=2)
```

To make my example reproductible, this is a part of the data set:

```
    > dput(Data[1:10,])
structure(list(hierarchical = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L), TYPE_PEAU = c(-0.57288314920011, -0.57288314920011, 
0.575705233678928, -0.57288314920011, -0.57288314920011, -0.57288314920011, 
-0.57288314920011, 1.72429361655797, 0.575705233678928, -0.57288314920011
), SENSIBILITE = c(0.778411858486852, -0.611121590654152, 0.778411858486852, 
0.778411858486852, 0.778411858486852, -2.00065503979516, 0.778411858486852, 
0.778411858486852, 0.778411858486852, 0.778411858486852), IMPERFECTIONS = c(0.153668403847404, 
0.153668403847404, 1.71724441299474, 1.71724441299474, -1.40990760529994, 
0.153668403847404, 0.153668403847404, 1.71724441299474, 0.153668403847404, 
0.153668403847404), BRILLANCE = c(0.611341816486383, 0.611341816486383, 
-1.72495977327848, 0.611341816486383, -1.72495977327848, 0.611341816486383, 
0.611341816486383, -1.72495977327848, -1.72495977327848, 0.611341816486383
), GRAIN_PEAU = c(0.721013947110648, 0.721013947110648, 0.721013947110648, 
-1.66478017056442, 0.721013947110648, 0.721013947110648, 0.721013947110648, 
-0.471883111726887, 0.721013947110648, -0.471883111726887), RIDES_VISAGE = c(0.76160293927347, 
-1.3761377247562, -1.3761377247562, 0.76160293927347, -1.3761377247562, 
0.76160293927347, 0.76160293927347, 0.76160293927347, 0.76160293927347, 
0.76160293927347), MAINS = c(-0.821850698542963, -0.821850698542963, 
0.859019825612744, 0.859019825612744, -2.50272122269867, -2.50272122269867, 
-2.50272122269867, 0.859019825612744, 0.859019825612744, 0.859019825612744
), PEAU_CORPS = c(0.138519340680625, 0.138519340680625, 0.138519340680625, 
0.138519340680625, 0.138519340680625, 0.138519340680625, 0.138519340680625, 
0.138519340680625, 0.138519340680625, 1.62213438428626), INTERET_ALIM_NATURELLE = c(-0.511256705293382, 
-0.511256705293382, 1.96590375964003, -0.511256705293382, -0.511256705293382, 
-0.511256705293382, -0.511256705293382, -0.511256705293382, -0.511256705293382, 
1.96590375964003), INTERET_ORIGINE_GEO = c(-0.615549348507463, 
-0.615549348507463, 0.523216946231343, 1.66198324097015, -0.615549348507463, 
-0.615549348507463, -0.615549348507463, -0.615549348507463, -0.615549348507463, 
1.66198324097015), INTERET_VACANCES = c(-0.674641038733191, 0.921747930827325, 
2.51813690038784, -0.674641038733191, -0.674641038733191, -0.674641038733191, 
-0.674641038733191, 0.921747930827325, 0.921747930827325, -0.674641038733191
), INTERET_ENVIRONNEMENT = c(-0.453247144592726, 2.22025412858466, 
2.22025412858466, 2.22025412858466, -0.453247144592726, -0.453247144592726, 
-0.453247144592726, -0.453247144592726, -0.453247144592726, 2.22025412858466
), AGE_INTERVAL = c(0.113315170554397, 0.113315170554397, 1.23817552215537, 
-1.01154518104657, -1.01154518104657, 0.113315170554397, 0.113315170554397, 
1.23817552215537, 1.23817552215537, 0.113315170554397), ATTENTE_BEAUTE_1 = c(-1.37923941425187, 
1.10241594207223, 0.10975379954259, 0.10975379954259, 1.10241594207223, 
1.10241594207223, -0.386577271722232, -1.37923941425187, -1.37923941425187, 
0.10975379954259), ATTENTE_BEAUTE_2 = c(-0.694553905243566, -0.694553905243566, 
-0.171066054439619, 1.39939749797222, 0.352421796364328, -1.21804175604751, 
0.352421796364328, 1.92288534877617, -0.694553905243566, -0.694553905243566
), MILIEU_VIE = c(-1.73846454742541, -1.73846454742541, 0.573806925784203, 
0.573806925784203, 0.573806925784203, 0.573806925784203, -1.73846454742541, 
-1.73846454742541, 0.573806925784203, 0.573806925784203), PROFIL_SELECTIONNE = c(-1.52468205833385, 
1.01853760454269, 0.11610482094134, 0.280183508868859, 1.18261629247021, 
0.936498260578933, -0.376131242841216, -1.11448533851505, -1.52468205833385, 
0.0340654769775807), NOMBRE_ACHAT = c(2.15193684769553, -0.0267653836778052, 
-0.843778720442807, 0.790247953087196, 0.517910174165529, 1.87959906877387, 
1.06258573200886, 2.15193684769553, -0.57144094152114, -0.843778720442807
), NOMBRE_CADEAU = c(1.27279390361087, -0.532178635656112, -0.532178635656112, 
-0.532178635656112, 1.27279390361087, 1.27279390361087, -0.532178635656112, 
1.27279390361087, -0.532178635656112, -0.532178635656112)), .Names = c("hierarchical", 
"TYPE_PEAU", "SENSIBILITE", "IMPERFECTIONS", "BRILLANCE", "GRAIN_PEAU", 
"RIDES_VISAGE", "MAINS", "PEAU_CORPS", "INTERET_ALIM_NATURELLE", 
"INTERET_ORIGINE_GEO", "INTERET_VACANCES", "INTERET_ENVIRONNEMENT", 
"AGE_INTERVAL", "ATTENTE_BEAUTE_1", "ATTENTE_BEAUTE_2", "MILIEU_VIE", 
"PROFIL_SELECTIONNE", "NOMBRE_ACHAT", "NOMBRE_CADEAU"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try increasing the boxplot margins with `par` and mess around with `cex.axis`, for the font size:

```
boxplot(d,las=2, par(mar = c(13, 5, 4, 2)+ 0.1), cex.axis=0.9)
```

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `par` command to resize it.

For x axis the required command is

`par(cex.axis = 0.6)` for instance.

If you need to resize the y-axis also,

`par(cex.lab = 1)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome! If it solves your problem, please check it as answer :)

Comment: this is basically my answer.

Comment: in terms of being basic, this is the more basic one. but this is not your point. I think you forget that you are not the only one who has this knowledge

Comment: I'm not implying that I'm the one with the knowledge, just the repetition of the same answer that doesn't improve what I said already. J.Con for example as a real different answer. Even better than mine.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I saw your reply when I posted it. if you look the time of the answer you can see that we have only 3 min difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the margins using graphing parameters (see more in `?par`).
What you can do is use `> par(mar=c(a,b,c,d),mgp=c(x,y,z))`
 and fill the letters in with values that best suit your case.
Then all that is left is `> boxplot(data,las=2)`
, where las=2 ensures that your labels are perpendicular to the axis (i.e. the test is written bottom to top, not left to right)

Comment: Also this is basically identical to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For greater control over your plot elements, you may like to use the `ggplot2` package. There are also a lot of great tutorials and vignettes for this package (like [this](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html) and [this](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html)).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

melt<-melt(frameDataClusterGrpe1)

ggplot(melt, aes(x=variable, y=value))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, angle=45, vjust=0.8, hjust=0.8))
```

[image]